# Apache error log permission issue after deleting in CWP

Tags: log-files, file-permissions, centos6.5, apache2

I am using CentOS Web Panel (CWP) and Apache as a web server. I have deleted the Apache `error_log` and recreated one using the command below:

```
touch error_log
```

I have successfully created the `error_log` but it didn't wrote any error to the file. I did some research and found that it might be due to:

1. wrong user, group
2. wrong file permission value

For first issue since in am using CWP it uses `nobody:nobody` for `user:group`. I have tried giving the permission of `700`, `600`, `644`, `755` and `777` but `error_log` file is always empty.

The file permission looks like this now:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root      4096 Aug 16 06:25 .
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root   root      4096 Jul 23 01:54 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root   3071646 Aug 16 13:49 access_log
-rw-r--r--   1 nobody nobody       0 Aug 16 06:25 error_log
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root         5 Aug 16 04:34 httpd.pid
-rw-------   1 root   nobody 1318922 Aug 16 13:49 suphp_log
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody root      4096 Jul 25 22:30 tmp
```

If there is anything that I am missing could anyone shade light over it?

Comment: Is there anything in the... oh, wait, never mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owner (user:group) should be root:root, permission 644

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3638790 2016-08-16 20:06 /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log

Restart apache after that and it will start to log.